# Prompt User to install a third party App from my iOS Application

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Feature to share Image via Instagram is a feature in my **iOS Application**:

**Scenario**

- User Installs my App from App store.
- He clicks button *Share image in Instagram*
- His Device doesn't have Instagram in it.
- Can I prompt user to Install instagram by redirecting him to App store or else by showing any Alert for the same?

Is there any possibility of App rejection while Apple review, stating prompting user to install a third party app or so?

Answer (score 1):

You can apple won't reject.If user has not required apps then you can show prompt to user to install apps if it's not or you can redirect app page in App store.Make sure your app should work without installation of others.But in your case you are just redirecting to specific apps.If your app can work on its own then no need worry.

From [App store Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#before-you-submit)

> 4.2.3 Your app should work on its own without requiring installation of another app to function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use iPhone *Hooks* described in Instagram Developers Website.

Here you will find all you nedd: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/